# How can I fix the IP address an API sees from my AWS Kubernetes pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a Drupal site running on an AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster.

But I need to access a 3rd party API that requires an IP whitelist, however when I run curl ifconfig.io I get different results each day.
Is there a way to fix this. 
My pod's Service domain resolves to 3 IPs however none of these are what a 3rd party sees when I try to access them.
Also does anyone know what this IP is called ?
Is this the Source IP?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a VPC in which your cluster is running needs to have an Internet Gateway with a static Elastic IP attached to it.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-public-private-vpc.html#create-EIP

Comment: It needs to have a NAT Gateway with an Elastic IP, not an Internet Gateway.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Fradley, can you please update here with whatever solution worked for you, as per above suggestions, Internet or NAT Gateway ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys, the elastic IP against the NAT worked for me.